# How to limit DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL activity visibility by schema or other possibilities to see activity for targeted schemas

Tags: oracle, database-administration

I am asking the DBA to turn on DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL logging and I am getting push back.  In some environments, I see change activity logged when I query this table, in other environments, I do not.

I am only interested in a handful of schemas. In my opinion, if my visibility of this table could be limited to the schemas that I have an interest in tracking, then there might potentially be less resistance to granting me access. What is the best way to grant me access to only the objects in a target schema list? Is there an alternate view that I could be granted access to?

Is there an existing Oracle view that limits row activity to only those objects that a user otherwise has visibility to or do we have to create our own view or more primitively, say, create a view like this

```
SELECT * FROM DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL WHERE OWNER IN ('schema1','schema2')
```

and limit SELECT access to the view? I'm not sure if this query is returning no rows in some envs because logging isn't turned on or whether I just don't have the proper access.

Answer (score 2):

Generally, it's best to install a database where you have access to everything (`DBA`, `SYSDBA` etc.) Then you can just lookup the documentation and try things out. You'll gain the trust of your DBAs much quicker if they notice that you know what you're talking about. For example [here](https://github.com/oracle/vagrant-boxes) or [here](https://www.oracle.com/downloads/developer-vm/community-downloads.html).

To your question: Auditing can be switched of totally for a database, but this is rare. If it is enabled, you need to enable it for a whole schema or for individual objects like tables. Restricting read access to `DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL` is good practice, as there is likely data in there that needs to be protected (like personal log ons etc).

Secondly, one has to be very careful about the amount of data that will be generated by enabling audit on a table. My DBAs enable it only for a short period of time and switch it off again to check how much data was generated.

A view that restricts data is an excellent idea, you should work together with the DBAs to create one for you.

EDIT: Apparently, and example is in order. Took a while as I had to switch on auditing which is disabled by default on Oracle's vagrant boxes.

As you suggest, a DBA could create `AS SYSDBA` a view on top of DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL filtering out a specific `OWNER`, or the current connected session (so that every user can see the audit actions of his/her own tables):

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW USER_AUDIT_TRAIL 
AS
SELECT *
  FROM DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL 
 WHERE username = SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','SESSION_USER');
```

Access to this view can be granted to you or to all users:

```
CREATE PUBLIC SYNONYM USER_AUDIT_TRAIL FOR SYS.USER_AUDIT_TRAIL;
GRANT SELECT ON USER_AUDIT_TRAIL TO PUBLIC;
```

Please do speak to the DBAs, they may want to exclude some columns and rows of the view from public exposure.

Answer (score 1):

I have not found an alternative view based on DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL ou UNIFIED_AUDIT_TRAIL.

I think that the solution is to create your own views with limited privileges.

Your DBA should be able to tell you if auditing is enabled or not, with or without unified audit trail and what is audited: actually he/she is very likely the only one being able to check this (unless there is some kind of separate role for database security administration).

Answer (score 1):

While someone could create a view as you suggest, it still wouldn't necessarily limit your access to the main audit trail, as access to the data dictionary in Oracle isn't fine grained. It tends to be all or nothing - so you could have a custom view, but you would *still* have access to DBA_AUDIT_TRAIL because the "SELECT ANY DICTIONARY" privilege would be required in most environments. The only way I can see that might work is to create the view in a dedicated application schema with the necessary privilege using definer's rights, then grant select access to that view to your account.

That said, auditing itself is very fine grained. If it isn't already enabled and being used by others, then it can be turned on only for what *you* want to audit, so there wouldn't be a need to create a custom view.